# Trying to understand linked list + Class concept

Tags: c#, visual-studio, getter-setter

I am studying Lists in C#, I have a big doubt, you see here, the property "Siguiente" is of the type of the same class, I dont understand how this affects the code internally and what actually means, the list works, that property is used to create the pointers in the list. My doubts are

1. On which regard does it affect having a variable of a type of the class inside the same class?
2. How does the system knows that this is functioning as a pointer ?
3. Are the values added in "Trabajo" ?

Adding the rest of the code, my main concern is on "CNodo" object.

Cheers

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

    namespace Lista_Ligada
    {
        class CNodo
        {
            private int vDato;

            private CNodo vSiguiente = null;

            public int Dato1 
                {

                    get => vDato; 
                    set => vDato = value ;

                }

            internal CNodo Siguiente
                {

                get => vSiguiente;
                set => vSiguiente = value;

                }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("[{0}]", vDato);
            }


            public void TextoPrueba()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Prueba");
            }



        }
    }
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Lista_Ligada
    {
        class CListaLigada
        {
            private CNodo   Ancla;
            private CNodo   Trabajo ;   
            private CNodo   Trabajo2;

            public CListaLigada()
            {

                Ancla = new CNodo();
                Ancla.Siguiente = null;

            }

            public void Transversa()
            {
                Trabajo = Ancla;
                Console.WriteLine("El ancla tiene un valor de Siguiente de {0}", Trabajo.Siguiente);
                Console.WriteLine("El ancla tiene un valor de Dato de {0}", Trabajo.Dato1);

                while (Trabajo.Siguiente != null)
                {
                    Trabajo = Trabajo.Siguiente ;
                    int D   = Trabajo.Dato1     ;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", D) ;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", Trabajo.Siguiente);              
                }

                Console.WriteLine();    

            }

            public void Adicionar(int pDato)
            {
                Trabajo = Ancla;

                while (Trabajo.Siguiente != null)
                {
                    Trabajo = Trabajo.Siguiente;
                }

                CNodo Temp = new CNodo();  // ? 

                Temp.Dato1      = pDato;
                Temp.Siguiente  = null;

                Trabajo.Siguiente = Temp;       

            }


        }
    }
```

```
using System;

namespace Lista_Ligada
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CListaLigada MiLista = new CListaLigada();

            CNodo Txt = new CNodo();

            MiLista.Adicionar(19);
            MiLista.Adicionar(3);
            MiLista.Adicionar(5);
            MiLista.Adicionar(7);
            MiLista.Adicionar(7);
            MiLista.Adicionar(5);
            MiLista.Adicionar(3);
            MiLista.Adicionar(1);
            MiLista.Adicionar(0);

            MiLista.Transversa();

            Txt.TextoPrueba();


            MiLista.Transversa();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code in your post rather than just posting images?

Comment: This is how linked lists work.  A Node will have a reference to the next node (or null if it's the tail of the list).

Comment: Your questions do not make sense to me, really. You have a field of the class type in the class. A legal thing to do. That's how you do "chains". What "internal effects" would you expect? 2. There are no "Pointers" (really in managed) C#. Since the type is a class and classes are reference types, the field holds a reference (of the class type). What do you expect "the system" to need to know outside that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class is not an instance of an object - a class describes how the object will behave and what data it will store.
If you have a class, that is declared like this:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        MyClass nextNode;
    }
```

That means, that an instance of this class will hold a reference to an object of the same class inside of it.
To create an instance of a class you call a constructor with the keyword `new`, f.e.:

`MyClass instance =  new MyClass()`

Now you have an instance of a class in your memory, and `instance` is a reference to it.
You have to understand, that `nextNode` inside `instance` is NOT an object - it is a reference to an object. So it is possible to write following lines:

```
    instance.nextNode = instance; //this will assign the same reference to nextNode as instance
    instance.nextNode = new MyClass(); //this will assign a reference to a different object with the same type MyClass
```

The image below roughly describes where references and objects are stored

[image]

The concept of linked list is strongly dependent of this logic, because you do not store objects inside of objects - you store references

[image]

Also, you are better off with creating more easy to understand questions with less code than a big one, that is hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

The Internet abounds with excellent tutorials of how linked-lists work – such as this one:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_algorithms.htm.  Therefore, let me please now refer you to one of them.

Class *instances* are implemented as dynamic objects – think *malloc()* – that are referenced by pointers.  Therefore you can construct linked-lists of them yourself.

Now, having just said all that, let me also say that *"you don't have to do this in real life."*  In object-oriented languages that provide "Classes," you will always also find convenient **container classes** which eliminate the need for you to go through the drudgery of actually creating a linked-list yourself ... except as a learning exercise.  You simply instantiate a container of the appropriate flavor and put things into it.  Used correctly, you know that the container *will* be bug-free, and you have easy access to some very sophisticated data structures in some containers' implementations.